# Error too many arguments to function 'void addBook()'

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error here and I've tried to fix it but nothing is working. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
int main()
{

FILE *fp;

if ((fp = fopen("C:books.dat", "rb")) == NULL) {

    printf("This file does not exist, Please add books ......\n");
     for (i=0; i< SIZE; i++)
        addBook(i);
}




delay = getchar();
delay = getchar();
 }
```

It's for C++ programme and I'm trying to create a library, also using file handling

Comment: Where is the addBook() function?

Comment: Show the definition of `void addBook()`

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because you are calling the function as

```
addBook(i);
```

But most probably, your function definition is something like

```
void addBook()
```

You need to pass an argument in it's definition. You should change it to

```
void addBook ( int i )
```

or something like that, or instead, remove the `i` from

```
    addBook(i);
```

---

After seeing your definition of `addBook()`, it is just as I said. The function is defined as

```
void addBook()
```

but you are calling it with

```
addBook(i);
```

The function was not expecting any arguments, but you called it with an argument, that's what caused the error.

Unless you need to send the value of `i` to the function `addBook()`, you should remove the `i` from the function call. That should fix that compilation error.